# DateTime.UtcNow return diffrent time in Windows and Windows Phone

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, utc

I have the following simple code :

```
var sampleTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

local time zone & date time on both desktop and smart phone is the same, but result of the code in Windows phone is 1 hour less than result of Windows !

for example with the same timezone & date time on both device my Windows return 7:40:10 AM and my Windows phone device return 6:39:05 AM !

Any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Maybe your phone has wrong date or time zone set?

Comment: What about daylight savings? Is it enabled on both devices?

Comment: What Time Zone are both devices set to?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know why/ when my date & time setting was changed to automatically ...

The problem solved .